# How to create my own linux display driver

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I am working on a project that uses an e-ink display connected to a board that runs a linux version using SPI. I can now control the display fine from user space but what I would really like to do is make a display driver so the e-ink display is seen as a normal display by linux. I have searched online on what I would have to do to make this work but I can't really find anything.

Could someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Can you provide hardware details of the board and eink display? Here is the Linux driver book
https://lwn.net/Kernel/LDD3/
You can always email Linux maintainers for questions.

Comment: @user1462442 writing a linux driver is not the problem. The problem is I don't where how to make a driver that allows my e-ink display to be seen as a standard monitor. The board is arm based SoC. and the e-ink display is a waveshare e-ink display with an SPI interface. Similar to this one https://www.aliexpress.com/item/296x128-2-9inch-E-Ink-display-module-SPI-interfac-Without-PCB-Communicate-via-SPI-interface-Supports/32811674328.html

Comment: which arm SoC? details are little sparse. Arm is a fragmented market

Comment: @user1462442 an ARM Cortex-A9. Not sure how this is relevant though.

Comment: Not helpful. What is the SoC chipset and maybe the board name?

Comment: Uses Mali-400 gpu 

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S5P4418
http://wiki.friendlyarm.com/wiki/index.php/NanoPC-T2

You should email the mali guys for questions

https://linux-sunxi.org/Mali

If only you choose a more open board, you can piggy back off of other people's work like raspberry pi 

https://github.com/juj/fbcp-ili9341

Please mention waveshare has a git repo to the mali developers

https://github.com/waveshare/e-Paper

https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=Mali-400-New-Open-Source

Go talk to rob clark etc. They might know what to do

Comment: I believe the irc channel is called lima. Ask them questions

Comment: @user1462442 Actually I was wrong it's not that board. It's a board without a gpu afaik. https://www.terasic.com.tw/attachment/archive/941/DE0-Nano-SoC_User_manual.pdf

Comment: Good luck. That board is completely different. https://github.com/RobertCNelson/socfpga-kernel-dev I cannot help anymore. I am not sure who you should contact. FPGA is much more different than a gpu

Comment: The nearest supported thing I can see in the Linux kernel sources is the [repaper](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/drivers/gpu/drm/tinydrm/repaper.c) driver for Pervasive Displays RePaper branded e-ink panels. Perhaps you could use that as a guide for implementing your own driver.

Comment: @user1462442 The FPGA is a peripheral device. It's not used at all as a GPU or anything even close.

Comment: @IanAbbott Thank you what I was looking for was the DRM. Not sure why everyone keeps talking about the e-ink display since my problem doesn't have much to with e-ink at all....

Comment: If it supports MIPI protocol, you may use `tinydrm` framework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please have a look at the existing "fbtft" drivers [here](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/drivers/staging/fbtft/fbtft_device.c?id=af8a41cccf8f469165c6debc8fe07c5fd2ca501a#n1170). Some Waveshare driver seems to be already supported and it might be what you are looking for or you can add support for the one you want. You can also have a look at the out of tree [fbtft](https://github.com/notro/fbtft) and [tinydrm](https://github.com/notro/tinydrm) driver repository.